# IOS submit to php and return data

Tags: php, ios

Hi there I'm new to making apps on IOS. I want to make a login section where a user enters their username and password. Then it submits behind the scenes to a php file on my server and checks if they are valid or not. It then must display the error/success text on in the app. I have so far started making the UI of the app and making minor adjustments of the code. But haven't had any luck to submit the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Send iPhone HTTP request to Apache PHP webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181751/send-iphone-http-request-to-apache-php-webserver)