# Fill PHP form from iOS

Tags: php, ios, forms, post

I have a view which has 4 text inputs on the iPhone. Also on the web I have a PHP form which has same 4 textboxes. I want to take the input data from iPhone and post to PHP form. Is it possible? If yes please explain which classes or frameworks should I use.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181751/send-iphone-http-request-to-apache-php-webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ASIHTTPRequest ( http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fallseeing-i.com%2FASIHTTPRequest%2F&ei=-dFZULfKO7SU0QW-1YGoAw&usg=AFQjCNFpUZprrMAY9mTk0aGzEzwSG8L9sg)
I use it to send POST data to php forms on my server and works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Send a POST request to your PHP script, with data keys with the same name as your form inputs'. Then display the value in your PHP form if a value is set.

```
<?php
    $somename = isset($_POST['somename']) ? $_POST['somename'] : '';
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="somename" value="<?php echo $somename; ?>" />
</form>
```

Obviously don't echo raw POST data, but that's the general gist of what you need to do.